# What is an appropriate place for me to ask this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have found a piece of free code online, which I am planning on implementing into my current code. I know that it can't be implemented the way it is, and want to ask others how they think the most effective way to change it would be. I have a specific idea for changing it, but I am new to this coding environment and am not sure if it is the right idea.

Where could I ask a question like this?

Comment: What does "most effective" mean?  Fastest?  Most readable?  Most likely to succeed?  Real questions have real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Make sure to put some work into your code explaining what you did!

Comment: I tried that recently, unfortunately an argument was started and my post was deleted. The code I am trying to implement is an entire class, the other classes are what I have written already. So when I asked how to change the code they argued that it wasn't my own code and was not suitable for Code Review.

Comment: @user14155 **Exactly**. Make some changes, and **explain** what you did. Then you might just get a better response :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I have just been hesitant to change anything because I really don't know much about the environment, and was worried I'd just end up breaking it. I'll make a copy of the file and start hacking away though...thanks for the friendly response, some people on here have been very cruel when I ask questions like this.

Comment: Well, you did try to just copy and paste the code with no attempts (or that's what looked like) of finding out how it works. They probably felt they had to make you give it a try and trust me it will be good for you if you do so. If you need help you can contact me and later we put on the forums for people who needs the same help you do now.

Comment: @user14155 IMO whether or not it's your code isn't relevant.